# Django when to use @staticmethod or @property

Tags: python, django

I keep seeing the following decorators used: `@staticmethod`, `@property` for example:

```
@staticmethod
def add_url():
    return reverse('add_user')

@property
def password_not_expired(self):
    return not self.password_expired
```

Could someone explain when to use one over the other? Say I want to add this code:

```
def get_user_type(self):
    return self.user_type
```

I would use a `@staticmethod` method right?

Comment: `@staticmethod` and `@property` are two **entirely** different beasts.

Comment: from my understanding @property is like a getter and setter. So if I don't want to change the dynamic value I should not use it right?

Comment: `@property` lets you use a getter, setter and/or deleter to handle an attribute. If you want something to appear as an attribute without having to call then you use a property. A `@staticmethod` allows you to stick a function on the class namespace without it actually being tied to the class. You still have to call that function.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can't use `self` in a `@staticmethod`.  Because the only thing `@staticmethod` does is make the function not be *passed* `self`.  Look in your own example: `add_url` doesn't take a `self` argument.

"static" here is in the entirely misleading sense of how C++ and Java use it.  A Python `@staticmethod` is really just a regular function that happens to live in a class, nothing to do with whether values are changed.

You can use `@property` without writing a setter.  In fact, that's probably the most common way to use it.

Comment: Why would you specifically want a decorator to specify that self cannot be passed into the method?

Comment: Typically when the method return an instance of the class, for example, rather than operating on an existing instance.

Comment: if you're returning an instance of the class, you should use `@classmethod` so inheritance works.  honestly, `@staticmethod` is incredibly rare and i don't think i've ever used it myself